# RAID vs Replication

Tags: replication

I'm kind confuse about it, can some one give me a hand with this...

1. Differences.
2. Which one is better.
3. Which one do you use and why?
4. Personal Opinion and advise.

Comment: Database replication, or storage-level replication?

Comment: They aren't even remotely related concepts.

Comment: Disk Storage Replication, which he probably meant by "Replication" (hence, the comparison to RAID), is quite similar to RAID 1 or Mirroring. Replication can be implemented across different networks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RAID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID) is a storage level function. You can use the various types of RAID apart from any RDBMS. RAID controllers are integrated with consumer-level products these days, so it's common even for home PCs to use it.

[Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx) in RDBMS terms is a mechanism for taking data from one place, and putting it somewhere else. Some flavors of replication allow for merging data that originates in more than one place.

You can go into quite a bit of depth on either subject, but they are very different things.

Comment: He probably meant Disk Storage Replication; hence the reference to RAID. Disk Storage Replication is quite similar to RAID 1 Mirroring, except that Disk Storage Replication can be implemented across the network.